# Universal type for return data from database

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns

I want to write a function, which should take SQL query as argument and give data as result.
So, I want that this function will give universal structure as result.
May be the best way to return `DataTable` or `SqlDataReader` ?
And after that to extract data from them and put it to the object with special type (different classes of models)?

May be exist some pattern for this?

Comment: Why not use Entity Framework or something like that?

Comment: I want to write SQL for getting more control of query. And the ORM can generate redundant queries. Thats why.

Comment: Based on the answers here this question is too vague. Can you expand your question to explain why you want a single generic Query command that returns objects of unknown type? Maybe with a code example?

Answer (score 2):

You can return the values directly to objects. But you will still need to map them eventually to something.

Normally for this sort of 'generic' use, I see everything being transferred as strings. Kind of how JSON gets serialized to some kind of string everywhere until it's ultimately used somewhere as something else.

Whether you use DataTable or something else, it really doesn't matter as it will ultimately end up being completely dependent on how you turn that data into something useful.

you can take a look at the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL page if you want to see some more info about that method.

Martin Fowler gave a presentation on schemaless and NoSql earlier this year that you may find interesting.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kotnF6hfd8

I would echo some of the other answers on here though and most likely advocate not doing something 'generic' or 'universal'. Just put in some work up front to make the system conform to what you definitely want to do and change it as needed.

Comment: JSON is good for transferring data, but it is much less powerful than a DataTable (or more refined model) for dealing with SQL results, so it really looks like SQL -> ?? -> JSON

Comment: depends. if you are writing a single page app and caching all of the data in JSON in some kind of NoSQL repo, it may all be JSON through and through. i guess my point was just the analogy that even 'typeless' structures like json really still have some kind of structure at some point because you have to tie them to something. I don't know that i would advocate for a solution like what is being suggested, but when/if i have seen things being made 'generic' for retrieval, the transfer mechanism seems to be strings.

Comment: In any case, +1 for "Whether you use DataTable or something else, it really doesn't matter as it will ultimately end up being completely dependent on how you turn that data into something useful." - which is to say that only the end-goal is ultimately of importance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just starting out. You may want to consider an ORM like Entity Framework Code First or NHibernate, or a MicroORM of which there are too many to list, rather than just running bare SQL against a db.

I find EF Code First to be great for beginners.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

ORMs let you define classes that map to the tables in your database, and ask for lists of those objects explicitly (solving the problem of what to return).

Comment: Code First is good for a "15 minute blog", but otherwise .. model First with the *correct* tooling is what I recommend.

Comment: @pst That's fine, we all have our preferences. I've found Code First a lot more flexible with regards to Migrations, but I'm sure we can find someone to tell us they hate both our approaches and NHibernate is the only way, so on and so on.

Comment: @pst Yes - you have to learn EF's gotchas either way, but we use it on... 5 or so production applications now? Very happy with it. But again - I'm sure we can find someone to tell us PicoORM is the best and we're both jerks.

Comment: Thank your for advice! But, I want to write SQL for getting more control of query. And the ORM can generate redundant queries. So, I'm trying to found pattern with types.

Comment: @Oleg A DAL/ORM - in whichever flavor, be it micro/mapper, code-first, generated, query wrapper, etc. - is to simplify work and unify the data-acess. The only time when I step outside the ORM (I use LINQ2SQL which is less ORM'ish than some) is when I do something *really awesome and complex* - which is fairly rare. Also consider that fighting with a DAL/ORM generally means that you're not a good fit for each-other. It might be time to break up :D

Comment: @ChrisMoschini W.r.t. migrations, what I use/recommend: updated SQL -> schema diff -> apply schema update scripts in sequence -> update model from SQL. I use "advanced" database features insofar as they don't conflict with LINQ2SQL and find that this approach allows me to very finely control and apply updates to production systems. The downside is that the schema change process must be serialized in the VCS (i.e. everyone must pull from master model branch), but also seems like it would affect CF. And I still can't understand "downgrades", however ..

Answer (score 0):

You could use c# [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) as return type. I would recommend [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) as ORM, it is fast and easy to use, and it has the functionality to return dynamics from an query, see the section:'Execute a query and map it to a list of dynamic objects'.

Comment: I recommend using `dynamic` as much as I recommend `object`. In most cases - ick! It also loses out on some of the really dynamic aspects of a DataTable (such as when the data is rolled up via a dynamic query into 0..n columns).

Comment: Who am i to question the minds of the great men at the Microsoft .NET team :-) Oleg wants what he calls 'universal structure' and  dynamic  is, in my world, what he is searching for.

Comment: While `dynamic` could allow `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, which would allow serial processing (depending on the query, etc), it is actually *less* dynamic than DataTable (much less DataTable/DataSet) when dealing with tabular data.